# Firebase CDN isn't gzip'ing index.html

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

My firebase app index.html is not served gzipped, as opposed to all other served assets.
Is there a workaround to have firebase serving a gzipped version?

see [my app](https://react-seo.firebaseapp.com/)

Comment: Firebase Hosting automatically gzips text resources as long as the request contains an Accept-Encoding header that allows for compression. Can you share the URL that's having the problem?

Comment: added in my post. I've checked and my requests are sent with `accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br`

Comment: Interesting. The initial response is not gzipped. But most of the subsequent requests are. I don't think there is anything you or I can do about that, so I've asked one of our hosting engineers to look into it.

Comment: Thanks. Can you update regarding this issue as an answer in this thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've opened a support ticket for firebase, and it seems like it's now fixed by their engineers.